# Laravel 5.4 - how to get and save database.sqlite located in the database folder

Tags: php, database, laravel, sqlite, laravel-5

I have a backup and restore database menu in my application, here I use sqlite for my database, I want to implement import and export database system like in phpmyadmin, and I am thinking of how to access database.sqlite in the database folder

I have tried it this way

```
<a href="/database/database.sqlite" class="btn">Backup</a>
```

and got the error

is there any way to get database.sqlite or maybe an easier way to backup and restore sqlite database on laravel 5.4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this file is not in `public` directory, you need to create a symbolic link between the `database` and `public/database` directories to make this work:

```
ln -s /full/path/to/laravel/database /full/path/to/laravel/public/database
```

Or you can create a controller method and [download](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/responses#file-downloads) this file with:

```
return response()->file(database_path('database.sqlite');
```

I also want to say that it's terribly insecure way yo backup the database and you should consider getting this file via SSH or something.

Comment: thanks, it works fine, but I do not get the name and extension of the file when trying to save it as in the picture 

[image](https://i.imgur.com/ZIkxody.png)

which I expect like this

[image](https://i.imgur.com/VYkceke.png)

Comment: @IndraSukmajaya pass file name as the second parameter. There is a link in my answer, you can read more about this by clicking the link.